# How to configure LSI RAID from ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, lsi, supermicro

I have a Supermicro AOC-USAS2LP-H8iR RAID card, which uses an LSI RAID controller.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the pre-bios prompt via IPMI (connections drops just before it gets there), so I'm trying to configure it via Ubuntu. I've seen references to megactl, megasasctl, megamgr, etc., but can't seem to get any of them working. How do I configure this card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I've found out that the correct utility to use for this card is the `storcli` utility. Conveniently, there is an APT repository available that packages this utility for ubuntu: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Thomas_Krenn_Ubuntu_Repository.

Comment: That no longer work unfortunately